# Best way to Map alphabets to Number

Tags: java

What is the best way to map alphabets to number. Use case:

```
'A' -> 1,
'B' -> 2,
'C' -> 3,
    .
    . 
'Z' -> 26
```

then it repeats again

```
'A' -> 27
'B' -> 28 
    .
    .
'Z' -> 52
```

And again

```
'A' -> 53
```

what is the best way to map this? for example say till the number 100

The expected out should be when an input 'A' is given, I need to get a list of corresponding numbers mapped to 'A'. in this case 1,27,53 ...

As I am new to Programming, the solution coming to my mind is switch case, enum etc. but I believe there is a better solution. I am using Java

Comment: What about associative arrays?

Comment: Do you mean you want to go the other way? You get a number as input and you want a letter as output?

Comment: @Sweeper not the other way

Comment: So if you get an input of a letter, say `A`, what's your expected output? 1 or 27 or 53?

Comment: @B001ᛦ lemme check associative arrays

Comment: @Sweeper 1,27,53 .

Comment: So you want a list of numbers? Please edit your question clarify that.

Comment: @Sweeper edited the question. thank you

Comment: Loop from 1 to 100 and feed a Map :)

Comment: @YassinHajaj did you mean a hash map? could you provide some sample code for the same?

Comment: You should read about the modulo-operation and converting ascii in char in java. With these two opportunities you can solve your task.

Comment: Yes à hashmap, I'm convinced you'll learn a lot more by looking it up yourself, good luck 

Comment: @YassinHajaj if it goes from 1 to 100, a simple array is more efficient and easier than a map.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle We don't need efficiency and a map will be easier to work with than an array and more readable ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a `char` to `int`. This will give you the ASCII value. Subtracting 64 will give you `1` for `'A'`. You can use this in a loop to print the index, at which point you will add 26 each iteration. In the example below, I use `maxNum` as a maximum index to print.

```
 /**
 * Prints indexes 
 * @param character     a character in the range 'A' <= character <= 'Z'
 * @param maxNum        the maximum value to output
 */
public static void printIndexes(char character, int maxNum) {
    int index = character - 64;
    while (index <= maxNum) {
        System.out.println(index);
        index += 26;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int index = character - 'A' + 1;` might be more clear than using the magic number 64.

Answer (score 3):

Your input is a `char`. For example :

```
char input = 'A';
```

You can use `input - 'A'` to get the difference between your letter and 'A'. Then use a `for` loop where you increase by `26` at each step until you reach 100 :

```
char input = 'A';

for (int i = input - 'A' + 1; i < 100; i += 26) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output** :

```
1
27
53
79
```

For the reverse operation, you would use a modulo 26 (operator `%`). A modulo 26 will map :

- 0, 26, 52... to 0
- 1, 27, 53... to 1
- 2, 28, 54... to 2

etc.

Here is the code :

```
int input = 27;
char output = (char)('A' + (input - 1) % 26);
System.out.println(output);
```

**Output** :

```
A
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using `Stream`s:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mapLetterToNumber('Z')));
}

public static int[] mapLetterToNumber(char c) {
    int firstNum = c - 'A' + 1;
    return IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1).map(x -> firstNum + x * 26).limit(100 / 26 + 1).filter(x -> x <= 100).toArray();
}
```

If you want it to go up to another number, replace `100` with that number.

If you want a certain number of elements in the array, remove the `filter` call and put that number inside `limit`. For example, if you just want five elements:

```
return IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1).map(x -> firstNum + x * 26).limit(5).toArray();
```

In Java 9, you can use `takeWhile` instead of a `limit` and `filter` call:

```
return IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1).map(x -> firstNum + x * 26).takeWhile(x -> x <= 100).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to convert letters to integers:

```
  public class MyClass
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      int index = Integer.parseInt("A", 36) - 9;
      System.out.println(index);
    }
  }
```

I realize your question is messed up, will fix my answer if you fix your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a HashMap to store each letter with its associated numbers (here I use string to separate the numbers by space) :

```
Map<Character,String> myMap = new HashMap<>();  

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
        if (myMap.containsKey(alphabet)) {
            myMap.put(alphabet, myMap.get(alphabet) + " " + String.valueOf(i++));
        } else {
            myMap.put(alphabet,String.valueOf(i++));
        }                     
    }
}    
System.out.println(myMap.toString());
```

Printing out the map produces the below :

> {A=1 28 55 82, B=2 29 56 83, C=3 30 57 84, D=4 31 58 85, E=5 32 59 86,
>   F=6 33 60 87, G=7 34 61 88, H=8 35 62 89, I=9 36 63 90, J=10 37 64 91,
>   K=11 38 65 92, L=12 39 66 93, M=13 40 67 94, N=14 41 68 95, O=15 42 69
>   96, P=16 43 70 97, Q=17 44 71 98, R=18 45 72 99, S=19 46 73 100, T=20
>   47 74 101, U=21 48 75 102, V=22 49 76 103, W=23 50 77 104, X=24 51 78
>   105, Y=25 52 79 106, Z=26 53 80 107}